# Motivation for hedging volatility using VIX ETNs

Tags: volatility, hedging, vix, etf

I wondered what the motivation for professional investors could be to trade in VIX ETNs.

Why would they even think about trading this kind of product? (They normally should have access to VIX options, futures or variance swaps.)

And if they do, has anyone a reasonable explanation? (Besides tight spreads, etc...)

Comment: Some interesting names on this list http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/vxx/institutional-holdings

Comment: Thanks for the link which already answers the first part of my question!